# OpenAPI/Swagger: Array in the response

Tags: yaml, swagger, openapi

I want to return a list of Activity's in a path. I tried to accive this by defining the Activity type in the items property:

```yaml
#...
# intendation is not correct here
responses:
  '200':
    description: Successful response
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/responses/Activity'
#...
components:
  responses:
    Activity:
      description: Activity object
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              id:
                type: integer
                format: int64
              author_id:
                type: integer
                format: int64
              amount:
                type: integer
                format: int64
              activity_type:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ActivityType'
              start_time:
                type: string
                format: date
              end_time:
                type: string
                format: date
```

But this doesn't result in a list of Activities but in:

```json
[
  "string"
]
```

How can I fix this/ implement a list of Activities as the return value? I already tried searching the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `response` reference takes a `Response Object` which contains the properties such as `content` and `description`. The body or `schema` of the response object should either point to another schema object or it can be defined inline. In your case, pointing to `#/components/schemas/...` is the correct way to define your example with the `type: array` and `items` keywords defined, because you want a collection response

```yaml
responses:
  '200':
    $ref: '#/components/responses/Activity_Response'
#...
components:
  schemas:
    Activity:
      description: Activity object
      schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          id:
            type: integer
            format: int64
          author_id:
            type: integer
            format: int64
          amount:
            type: integer
            format: int64
          activity_type:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/ActivityType'
          start_time:
            type: string
            format: date
          end_time:
            type: string
            format: date
  responses:
    Activity_Response:
      description: Successful Activity response
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Activity'
```